# TinyMCE Content_css isn't working

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc-3, tinymce

I am using TinyMCE with MVC 3 razor engine. I am trying to add my own classes I used content_css and added my style sheet. the classes appeared normally in the drop-down list but when i click them they don't affect the view or html. where should I look or inspect I'm using version 3.4.7

Comment: `Google Chrome` Right Click -> Inspect Element?

Comment: @Archio it doesn't affect the html i can see it if press the html button

Comment: you should use firebug or another tool to inspect the dom. please tell me if your css is to be found in the editor iframes head. can you show us your full tinymce configuration
?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the problem was with the tinymce version

Comment: 8 years later, the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

It can be a bug wiht tinymce. You can grab the lastest version and try.

Also consider migrating to [ckeditor](http://ckeditor.com/). Its a great editor and have support for a bunch of plugins. It's also highly customizable and esasy to implement and setup.